# How to execute the python code below __name__== '__main__ ' *without* using the `subprocess` module?

Tags: python

I have a python script with the form

```
...
if __name__=='__main__':
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   #code
```

From another python script, how can I execute the code below `__name__ == '__main__'` *without* using the `subprocess` module?

[Edit] In addition, my python script takes input parameters with the `argparse` module. I also need to pass parameters when executing the code below the `__name__` part.

Comment: You keep this `if __name__=='__main__':`, to not to execute code under this block, while running this code from another `.py` file by importing.

Comment: Remove `if __name__=='__main__':`

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the question. I also need to pass parameters. So it looks like importing would not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might be able to get away with:

```
import sys
imp_new_module = type(sys)
new_module = imp_new_module(module_name)
new_module.__dict__['__name__'] = '__main__'
exec(open(scriptname).read(), new_module.__dict__)
```

But you shouldn't do it... :)

(updated question)

Oh, since you're at it you can also `import os, sys` and then update `sys.argv` to what you want to pass on (e.g. `sys.argv = [os.path.abspath('file.py'), '--my', 'par'])` ... did I mention that you really shouldn't?

Seriously, if you have control over the script that you are calling you might want to put the code under `if __name__ == '__main__':` in a function

```
def main(argv):
    ... 
    parser.parse_args(argv)
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Or better still define a function (or functions, object) in the script that provides an API better suited to be called from a script, which is also called from `__name__ == '__main__'` based on what is found in `sys.argv`.